# How to convert varchar to image datatype in SQL?

Tags: sql, image, type-conversion, sql-server-2014, sqldatatypes

I have a C# web application, and it's job is to send the captured image to database in bytes form, which is data type image in SQL. The issue here is that the DAL of the website does not allow me to send bytes through it, even the web-services are not allowing me to do it. So I am trying to figure out: what if I convert the bytes to a plain string and then in the stored proc convert it back to data type image and store it. Is that possible?

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertpic]
    (
        @ID             int , 
        @CapturedPhoto image -- Maybe get this << Data type as NVARCHAR and convert to data typeImage?
    )
AS

if exists (select * from tbpeople where ID=@ID)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE tbPeople 
    SET      
             DateCapturedPhoto = getdate(),
             CapturedPhoto=@CapturedPhoto
    WHERE   ( ID= @ID)

    END 
Else 

    Begin

    INSERT INTO tbPeople        (   
            ID
            , CapturedPhoto
        )
    VALUES
        (   
              @ID 
                        , @CapturedPhoto
        )
END
```

Comment: Why does your DAL not allow you to send a byte array through it?

Comment: The companies security reasons I cant change that the system is too big and they all based on that DAL that's the reason I have to work around it

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to jump through a few hoops to make this work, but the general approach would be to first capture the image into a `base64` string.

```cs
var encodedImageString = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

From there, you can pass the string into your stored procedure. You'll then have to convert it back into binary.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertpic]
(
    @ID INT, 
    @EncodedCapturedPhoto VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS

DECLARE @CapturedPhoto IMAGE

SET @CapturedPhoto = cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@EncodedCapturedPhoto"))', 'VARBINARY(4000)');

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbpeople WHERE ID=@ID)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbPeople 
    SET      
             DateCapturedPhoto = getdate(),
             CapturedPhoto=@CapturedPhoto
    WHERE   ( ID= @ID)

END 
Else 

    Begin

    INSERT INTO tbPeople        (   
            ID
            , CapturedPhoto
        )
    VALUES
        (   
              @ID 
                        , @CapturedPhoto
        )
END
```

Comment: Let me give this a try.

Comment: Ok its giving me Error when I try to run the SQL script it says the DECLARE @CapturedPhoto IMAGE  Error:The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.

Comment: @Maxi I updated the solution to use `VARBINARY` instead of `IMAGE`. You'll likely still have to do some tweaking. You can also checkout this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36388.transact-sql-convert-varbinary-to-base64-string-and-vice-versa.aspx